Excel Ribbon Button toggleButton: Chart Protect Formatting
This is a toggleButtonto switch Chart.ProtectFormatting on/off.
How do you build it to always "show" the active charts' state?
If Not TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then Exit Sub does not work.
' -- XML

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" 
 onLoad="LoadRibbon">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                  
        <group id="Group6" label="Protect Formatting">
          <toggleButton id="ToggleButton4" 
                        label="ChtLock" 
                        imageMso="Lock" 
                        size="large"
                        getPressed="ToggleButton4_Startup" 
                        onAction="ToggleButton4_OnAction"/>       
        </group>           
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>


' -- Standard Module

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton4"
End Sub

' ToggleButton 4 Startup
Sub ToggleButton4_Startup( _
   ByRef control As IRibbonControl, _
   ByRef returnedVal)
   'If Not TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then Exit Sub
   returnedVal = (ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting) = True
End Sub

' ToggleButton 4 Click
Sub ToggleButton4_OnAction( _
   ByRef control As IRibbonControl, _
   ByRef pressed As Boolean)
   'If Not TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then Exit Sub
   Select Case pressed
      Case True
          ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting = True
      Case False
          ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting = False
   End Select
End Sub


' -- ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton4"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ToggleButton4"
End Sub


You'd need to capture some event related to selecting a chart, but I'm not sure such a thing exists.

It's same as your previous post. When the user selects a chart, it doesn't trigger the Workbook/Sheet event code. Therefore, there's no way to refresh the Ribbon with RibUI.InvalidateControl.

You could use his approach but you'd need to keep track of all embedded charts and hook up events for each one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-events-with-embedded-charts

One alternative:
Sub ToggleButton4_OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Select a chart.", vbExclamation
  Else
  On Error Resume Next
  With ActiveChart
    If .ProtectFormatting = False Then
      .ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
          Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
      .ProtectFormatting = True
    Else
      .ProtectFormatting = False
      .ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange. _
          Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
  End With
  MsgBox ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting, _
  Title:="Active Chart" & vbNewLine & "Protect Formatting"
  End If
End Sub

It's still a toggle button. And it gives you feedback:

Chart Unprotected: ChartTitle color = red
Chart Protected: ChartTitle color = black

You just need to plot your chart title in red for this to work.
